# How to append the success data in an element as URL action with parameter

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ajax call and I get a list of properties. How can I append one of the list items as a href with post method to Action controller in MVC?

```
    success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            for (var i in data) {
                $('#searchPropertiesListTableBody').append("<tr><td><a href='@Url.Action("ViewProperty", "Property")'>" + data[i].PropertyId + "</a></td></tr>");
            }
        },
```

Comment: `href='@Url.Action("ViewProperty", "Property")' + "/" + data[i].PropertyId + ">"` (assuming you want a route value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  var ActionU='@(Url.Action("ViewProperty", "Property"))';
  $.each(obj,function(key,value) {
      $('#searchPropertiesListTableBody').append("<tr><td><a href='"+ ActionU +"?PropertyId="+value.PropertyId+"'>" + value.PropertyId + "</a></td></tr>");
    });
```